# Access nested select in field listing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been provided a query to search for some data in the db that looks like this:

```
select nvl(to_char(a.empresa), 'SEM REMESSA') empresa,
      c.conta,
       nvl(sum(a.valor_total), 0) as folha,
       (select count(distinct(l2.creditado))
          from lancamentos l2
         inner join vw_arquivos a2
            on l2.arquivo = a2.arquivo
         where a2.empresa = a.empresa) as funcionarios
  from conta_table c
  left join vw_arquivos a
    on c.conta = a.conta
   and a.situacao = 6
  group by a.empresa, c.conta
```

I have to get the value of the operation `folha / funcionarios`, but if I put this in the field listing I get the error:

```
ORA-00904: "FUNCIONARIOS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

And when I replace my reference to `funcionarios` with the same nested select, I get the same error on reference `folha`.

I know I could just replace both references with their respective calculations, and it works. Like this:

```
nvl(sum(a.valor_total), 0) / 
(select count(distinct(l2.creditado))
          from lancamentos l2
         inner join vw_arquivos a2
            on l2.arquivo = a2.arquivo
         where a2.empresa = a.empresa) as division
```

But this looks not so optimized and not like the best way to do it. So my question is...
Is there any way to select these values with this last division operation, but more optimized than repeating the `folha` and `funcionarios` calculations? Maybe a way to reference these already calculated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`folha` and `funcionarios` cannot be referenced in the same query because they are aliases. You have to make the entire query as subquery, and get the division, like so:

```
select empresa, conta, folha/funcionarios folha_div_funcionarios
from (
  select nvl(to_char(a.empresa), 'SEM REMESSA') empresa,
        c.conta,
         nvl(sum(a.valor_total), 0) as folha,
         (select count(distinct(l2.creditado))
            from lancamentos l2
           inner join vw_arquivos a2
              on l2.arquivo = a2.arquivo
           where a2.empresa = a.empresa) as funcionarios
    from conta_table c
    left join vw_arquivos a
      on c.conta = a.conta
     and a.situacao = 6
    group by a.empresa, c.conta
)
```